# for range - invalid syntax of loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, range

```
def amp1(array):
    for i in range (0,len(array),400)
    amp1 [array]= abs(max(array[i:i+400]))
    return amp1

print(amp1(node1[3]))
```

I get this response:

```
File "<ipython-input-53-972793b81fd0>", line 7
    for i in range (0,len(array),400)
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a ":" at the end of line 7.
Let try like:

```
def amp1(array): 
    for i in range (0,len(array),400): 
        amp1 [array]= abs(max(array[i:i+400])) 
    return amp1

print(amp1(node1[3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a : at the for loop, `for i in range (0,len(array),400):`